# What goes on in an Orthodox Women's Rosh Chodesh celebration?

Tags: tefilla, women, rosh-chodesh-new-month

I am vaguely aware that in some Orthodox communities, there are Women's Rosh Chodesh celebrations.  As I do not live in such a community (and in any case am not a woman), I don't really have any idea what goes on in such an event.  I imagine there is usually some learning; I have also seen references online to [reading Tehillim](http://www.chabad.org/theJewishWoman/article_cdo/aid/607803/jewish/How-does-a-Jewish-woman-celebrate-Rosh-Chodesh.htm) or special [Rosh Chodesh *tekhines*](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/women-and-rosh-chodesh/), but these lack specifics.  I have also seen a number of sites that talk about inventing modern Jewish women's rituals, but these mostly seem to be aimed at a non-Orthodox audience.

I don't expect any kind of definitive answer of what *should* be done -- I assume there is no normative *halakha* on this -- but it would be very helpful to have a sense of the parameters governing what *could* be done, or what is typical at such events.

Comment: Some women have a custom not to do Melakha on Rosh Chodesh (pseudo-[source](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69062/759))

Comment: What could be done would certainly be on topic.what is done, might not be.

Comment: @mevaqesh  I am certainly interested in both, but presumably (?) if these are events sponsored by Orthodox organizations, and done with the approval of an Orthodox rabbi, then what *is* done would be a subset of what *may be* done.

Comment: @mweiss Agreed.

Comment: @mevaqesh what is done for _rosh chodesh_ as an expression of Judaism is squarely on-topic.

Comment: @msh210 You do not seem to be adding anything to demonstrate Judaism-not-Jews; just dogmatically repeating a position.

Comment: @mevaqesh, yes, same as you. Couldn't let your comment go uncountered, lest passersby think it's the community's view (which I don't think it is).

Comment: @msh210 I wrote: `might not be` as a prompt for further conversation. I made no dogmatic assertions of what is `squarely on-topic`.

Answer (score 1):

Historically, there was a precedent for women (and, I guess men, as well) to visit the prophet as we see in [Kings II 4:23](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14263&st=&pgnum=265). I assume, then, that this may have set a precedent for women to gather on Rosh Hodesh to hear a shiur from the rav followed by a Rosh Hodesh *seudah* (meal).

This is done in my neighborhood - one consisting of numerous shuls - I stopped counting them! For practical reasons, though, few shiurim are done on Rosh Hodesh, itself unless it's on Shabbat. Usually it is done on the Shabbat preceding Rosh Hodesh. Most women either work or are busy with their kids during mid-week.