# How were women rewarded for not worshiping the Golden Calf?

Tags: history, women, reward-punishment, golden-calf-egel

The Leviim were rewarded for not participating in the Egel (golden calf) by replacing the Bechorim (firstborn) as the workers in the Mishkan.

But the women also did not participate in the calf.

What reward did they receive?

Comment: Rosh Chosesh as a holiday

Comment: @robev https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69061/chodesh-asur-min-hatorah/69062

Comment: @Robev what do you mean? Doesn't everyone celebrate Rosh chodesh? Additionally the Leviims award seems greater than Rosh chodesh

Comment: Only women refrain from melacha on RH. Only the leviim helped Moshe enact justice after the eigel

Comment: Although not directly connected to this post. The sfas emes says that korach decided he should be the kohen godol rather than Aaron because he did not do the egel whereas Aaron did.

Comment: @Orion PRE ([ch. 45](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.45.4?with=all&lang=bi)) is source for @ robev. However, see Bet Yosef ([OC 417](https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Yosef%2C_Orach_Chaim.417.5.1?with=all&lang=bi)) who attempts to reconcile the tradition that initially RC was "given" to the twelve tribes but ultimately "taken" from them save for the women.

Comment: @robev (& Orion & Oliver)   (I know only 1 @ will work) -  What is the source that the women " did not participate in the calf. "? The sources given show that they were rewarded for not giving up their jewelry for the making of the calf, but maybe eventually when the rest of the people participated in the *eigel* they joined too. Whereas the Leviim did not participate at all.